# Account Lockout with pam_faillock in RHEL6

Tags: redhat, pam, rhel6, user-accounts, hardening

Previously, I asked about using [pam_tally2 under RHEL6](https://serverfault.com/q/447230/50647). I would like to pose this question and answer to document the recommended use of **pam_faillock** *over* **pam_tally2** for the same function;

**What is the recommended strategy for temporary account locking in Red Hat 6?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pam_faillock module was introduced to us in the [Technical Notes for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.1_Technical_Notes/pam.html). And somehow this flew under my radar until now.

> BZ#[644971](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=644971)
>   A new pam_faillock module was added to support temporary locking of user accounts in the event of multiple failed authentication
>   attempts. **This new module improves functionality over the existing
>   pam_tally2 module, as it also allows temporary locking when the
>   authentication attempts are done over a screen saver.**

The [Security Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-Security_Guide-Securing_Your_Network.html#sect-Security_Guide-Workstation_Security-Administrative_Controls) explains to us how this module should be used in section 2.1.9.5, Account Locking.

> Follow these steps to configure account locking:
>
> To lock out any non-root user after three unsuccessful attempts and unlock that user after 10 minutes, add the following lines to the
>   auth section of the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` files:
>
> ```
> auth        required       pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
> auth        sufficient     pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
> auth        [default=die]  pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
> ```
>
> Add the following line to the account section of *both* files specified in the previous step:
>
> ```
> account     required      pam_faillock.so
> ```

I've intentionally stopped here because this will provide the functionality that most are looking for. If you wish to include the root user, read on at the link provided.

Comment: Great reply but the section is: 2.1.9.5, Account Locking.